# What to do about identical questions posted minutes apart

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

While browsing recent questions on one of my favorite tags I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299334/java-recursion-and-class-object-with-factorial) and [this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35299421/creating-class-object-to-do-factorial-recursion) They both have the exact same text and code with a minor format change and were asked by 2 different users 4 minutes apart. This seems a bit strange to me. I think it would be one of two situations:

1. One user posted a question and then another user copy/pasted that question.
2. These two users are classmates and by mere chance happened to post the exact same text when asking for help with their homework.

Case 1 seems more likely to me because one of these users is brand new (8 days on the site) and the other is older (2 years). I flagged one of the posts as a duplicate of the other. However, the original post had no upvoted answers whereas the second had an upvoted answer so I was only able to flag the earlier post as a duplicate of the later post. This feels a bit unfair to the first user if their question gets blatantly stolen and then used to close their post as a duplicate. It also might be of interest to note that these questions share an identical answer posted on each one by the same (third) user about 10 minutes apart. Is there any other action that I should take in a situation such as this?

Comment: You may want to flag one of the posts for moderator attention if you suspect [*sock puppet*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/sock-puppets/info) activity.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When you see a word-for-word duplicate of a question posted by a different user, I'd recommend using a custom moderator flag on the newest question. State that this new question is a word-for-word duplicate of the older question and link to it. That's really easy for us to judge, as it was here.

Moderators can then close as a duplicate and possibly merge the questions if they received answers (like happened here).

It also may point to a larger problem, because we often see this behavior with users evading question bans or employing sock puppets to get their questions more exposure. In this case, it looks like students working together on the same project.

Comment: Afaik, there is some automated process behind word to word copied answers ... Aint there anything like that for questions?

Comment: @BhargavRao - Even for answers, that only detects duplicate answers by the same person, not by different people. Community members can run queries to find plagiarized answers, but there's nothing at the system level to detect duplicate posts by different people yet.

Comment: Oh, Sigh. Then you guys definitely need a kind of plagiarism detector. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I don't particularly like flagging for stuff like this - you mods have enough to do with suspending over-honest closers/commenters, (sorry:).   I usually just run around the questions and DCV all of them.  If you really do want notifications re. these homework dups, then I will be happy to provide them in future, eg. for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168306/how-to-quadruple-an-unsigned-number-using-bit-wise-and-logic-operator-in-c which is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276670/floating-point-multiplication-using-bit-manipulation

Comment: @BhargavRao Please see this meta post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274553/245360