# How to handle copy-and-pasted Answers from dupes

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-answers

I came accross yet another [floating point question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36383503/is-floating-point-math-in-c-broken), which is now closed as a duplicate.

A user answered this question by litterally just copy and pasting the accepted answer from the ["canonical" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) (he appended the link to the original answer, but didn't format it as a quote). I left a comment that he should not c&p answers and rather flag the question as a duplicate and/or refer to the duplicate in a comment.

Although it is now removed anyway, I was wondering **if such pure c&p answers are allowed at SO at all** (as it wasn't an actual case of plagiarism) and if one should flag them for moderator intervention or e.g. just comment and edit it to make it more clear, that this is a pure c&p answer?

Comment: FYI an auto flag is raised if an answer is an exact copy and paste of another answer.

Comment: A low-rep user is not allowed to mark questions as dupes, up/down vote, or even comment on anything that isn't their own answer/question. They have nothing to offer except an answer (they found) they think would be useful to the user that asked the question. Doesn't seem like a bad thing that they share it, and site their source.

Comment: @Nathan: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. Is there some list of SO's automatic filters and flashing mechanisms? Or is that deemed too dangerous?

Comment: @mikemb there is a meta question asked like a month or two ago by George Stocker I believe that list them all

Comment: @NathanOliver Brad mentioned on [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316536/what-to-do-about-identical-questions-posted-minutes-apart) that the auto flag is only raised when a user copies and pastes one of their own answers. There isn't an auto flag for direct c&p of another user's answer.

Comment: @Rainbacon Ah yes.  even from [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317988/4342498) it will only be raised when the user posts duplicate answers

Comment: From the related sidebar: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285349/how-to-handle-answers-which-copy-its-whole-content-from-another-answer-with-prop?rq=1

Comment: [If only people could score rep &/or badges for finding dupe targets...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316652/4014959)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

No, pure copy-paste answers are not allowed, because if they were, then there's no point in marking anything as duplicate, since the whole idea behind that is to prevent answers from being duplicated across multiple questions.

Feel free to flag such answers for moderator attention, even if proper attribution is provided (in this case, the proper quotation formatting is missing). Be sure to state that they are copied wholesale or verbatim from an answer to the duplicate target. It's one thing to use other works to support your own, and another to simply profit off of someone else's work wholesale with no contribution of your own — all while creating redundancy in the process. Plagiarism becomes a bit less pertinent here.

Comment: I expect to see this answer of mine again in a future meta question.

Comment: Then, somewhere in your answer, write something like "You have BoltClock's permission to flag it...". Copy/pasters are usually in hurry. So, the pure copy/pasted answer will still have your name! LOL.

Comment: Btw. this answer is almost a pure copy (not word by word but meaning by meaning) of another answer of [BoltClock in August 2014](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269406/1536976). Instead of answering here and creating redundancy in the process... :)

Comment: @Trilarion: It's OK because I'm copying my own answers! (But in all seriousness, while the idea behind not duplicating content is the same, the context behind that answer is different - it's about editing a competing answer to have the same information as another answer.)

Comment: @BoltClock You're right, although you also could generalize it a bit. It's the same thing really, you never make a pure copy of another answer neither at the same question nor for a dupe because it just adds redundancy. Additionally it's not a good idea to answer dupes at all.