# Declined flag on answer copying another answer in its entirety, although with attribution

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, declined-flags, specific-answer

I've recently custom flagged this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52297393/1426539

> [image: copied answer]

Which is a complete copy of another answer (which funnily enough already consists entirely of a quote and its attribution):

> [image: original answer]

The complete text of my flag was:

> Just a repost of a different answer. Directly linked in the post as well... (stackoverflow.com/questions/1164899/ie7-popup-hide-the-url-‌​bar)

The response was:

> declined - it's attributed and allowed

I do not understand the decline reason.

Shouldn't answers that copy another answer entirely although using proper attribution be [flagged for moderator attention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320352/1426539)? (Feel free to close as a dupe to that one, although I'd like to know if that stance has changed since that answer was posted, in light of this flag's results).

Maybe my description wasn't complete enough, and I apologize for that, but the decline reason makes me think the mod did read both answers and made their own judgement, so a more accurate flag description wouldn't have made a difference.

Even if I didn't flag for plagiarism, I would argue that the attribution is kinda weak here: The link doesn't point to the answer but to the question, and the attribution should probably go the the primary source, not to the already quoting answer...

Nevertheless, not arguing a plagiarism flag, but would like to know in if either I erred and misinterpreted the guidance in this case or if we should avoid flagging cases like these in the future.

Apparently the question was deleted (likely due the additional meta-scrutiny this question brought), but my point is less about "lets delete this answer" and more about the flag handling and how should we flag these cases.

Even if this was "handled" by the community, a meta post was required, and the community deletion will possibly have to be reviewed by a mod anyway.

Comment: Don't forget to vote to close the question as a duplicate if you haven't done that, yet.

Comment: Regarding your question: as far as I know it isn't forbidden to use the answer of another question to answer "this" question, just highly discouraged, because the answerer should have voted/flagged to close the question instead. That is why the answer is downvote-worthy (if you want), but not flaggable, since it provides attribution.

Comment: @Tom Please read Bolt's answer in the question I linked. I flagged because of answers like that encourage users to flag useless posts like these.

Comment: Just to make it clear: I'm with you (and with Bolt in their answer) that such answers shouldn't exist, but I'm not sure the majority of SO community members would agree. Regarding Bolts answer: I don't know (but hope) that this still matches current SO guidelines. We will see what the moderator says, when they post an answer to explain their decision.

Comment: @yivi, Thx for asking the question. I have flag the quetion as dupe. Saw the matching answer but was puzzle on the way to handle it. Was on my SO todo list.

Comment: Copying complete answers instead of dupe-closing could is not acceptable by a user with 5k+ reputation. They should now already how to close vote.

Comment: Does anyone see a problem if I copy BoltClocks answer (with proper attribution) to this question here?

Comment: I flagged a lot of answers like that before and flag was accepted and answer deleted

Comment: Answer is deleted now, I am less than 10k but going off the last comment it is likely it was deleted in the LQ posts queue for being link only

Comment: Before saying it's a duplicate, look at the question not at the answers! What if the user is wrong and that answer doesn't answer the question?

Comment: @Braiam then that user still should have VTCed instead of posting an answer.

Comment: @TheWanderer wait, what? If they posted something that doesn't answer the question, why should it be closed?

Comment: @Braiam they think it answers the question, otherwise they wouldn't have posted it as an answer. If you think an already-existing answer works, then you should VTC, not repost the answer. If it isn't actually a duplicate... well that's why we need 5 votes, a gold badge, or a mod.

Comment: @TheWanderer I think you are misunderstanding my comment. I'm telling other voters to not simply follow this user judgement, but to form one themselves. I don't care what the user should do, I care whenever others follow the same potentially misguided path.

Comment: This is an unambiguous case of plagiarism by the site's own plagiarism rules.  There is no justification for declining a flag like this.  Sadly this doesn't seem like an isolated incident, I've noticed numerous cases recently of mods refusing to act on cases of plagiarism.

Comment: @Servy It isn't [plagiarism](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism). Plagiarism is representing work done by someone else as your own. Just providing a link to the page containing the source and saying it's from that page makes it not plagiarism. However, just a link to the question page on which the answer exists isn't sufficient attribution under CC BY-SA 3.0, or the SE TOS. In addition, there's the already mentioned issue of should answers that are just attributed copies of another answer be something we find acceptable. However, those are different issues than plagiarism.

Comment: @Makyen That page, in addition to SO's definition of plagiarism specifically states that quoting and citing the work of others without adding sufficient original new content is also plagiarism.  To quote your own source's definition, "Relying too heavily on other people's work. Fails to bring original thought into the text."  SO's definition of plagiarism has a similar statement, saying, "Do not copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own."

Comment: @Makyen That the content is licenced to allow copying means it's not a copyright violation, which is a strictly legal question, rather than a question of plagiarism (which is simply a question of what is considered acceptable by a community's standards, and is not a legal matter).

Comment: [Attribution is *required*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing); that includes naming the person who wrote the answer. Your flag was wrongly declined. Period. [The guidance has not changed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268629/how-do-we-deal-with-plagiarized-answers/268630#268630).

Comment: @Servy Actually, it is a copyright violation, because they don't comply with the attribution requirements in the license. Such licenses grant the right to copy under certain specified conditions, not just whenever you feel like it, without regard to the conditions specified in the license. As to your arguments about SE's definition of plagiarism, I'm using "[Plagiarism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism) - posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own", found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Comment: @Servy As to the 10th type listed in Wikipedia's page under "Common forms of student plagiarism": "[Relying too heavily on other people's work. Fails to bring original thought into the text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism#Common_forms_of_student_plagiarism)": that is from a survey of teachers, and doesn't, necessarily, actually define plagiarism. It's just what those surveyed teachers were lumping into that category. I significantly disagree that, as written, that description is plagiarism. It's something that should get a bad grade, but isn't actual plagiarism, IMO.

Comment: @Servy Perhaps we're being to pedantic in this discussion. I think we can both agree that, as Cody Gray has stated, SE requires attribution. I think the main difference of our positions is that you are calling a lack of full, correct attribution plagiarism, while I'm using a more narrow definition of plagiarism, but calling a lack of full, correct attribution a copyright and/or TOS violation.

Comment: @Makyen So now you're saying that *the source you cited* of plagiarism is wrong?  Not only does *your own source* say this is plagiarism, but SO's rules say it's plagiarism, and you have no references that say it isn't (not that it matters, because SO has stated it's plagiarism *here*, which is all that matters).

Comment: @Servy No, Wikipedia quite clearly states the 10 items listed in that section are from the "2015 survey of teachers and professors by Turnitin" ([ref](//go.turnitin.com/paper/plagiarism-spectrum)), which is a company making money off detecting plagiarism (i.e. they are biased). Where does SE state the definition of plagiarism you're using? You keep saying that, but have yet to provide a reference. The [SE page I linked](/help/referencing) gives a succinct definition of plagiarism. It then goes on to list the referencing requirements for SE, which is not the same as defining "plagiarism".

Comment: @Makyen Why are you trying to refute the credibility of *your own source*?  If you don't think that's a suitable definition of plagiarism then why did you put it forth as a source for what plagiarism is, and use it as your justification for your assertion that this isn't plagiarism?  Likewise the SE page describing what plagiarism is covers this behavior.  That's it's at the end of the remarks on plagiarism instead of the start doesn't mean it can just be ignored.  It's still just as much a part of the plagiarism definition provided on that page.

Comment: @Servy, I suggest that when you are reading, you pay more attention to, and read a bit more accurately, the details in what is written, how it's organized, how it's referenced and sourced, etc. You appear to be continuing this discussion, just to have an argument. You've chosen not to just accept that we disagree. I, frankly, don't really care all that much what definition you personally use for the word "plagiarism", so have no real need to convince you. Because you appear to be continuing this conversation just to be argumentative, I'm just going to disengage.

Comment: @Makyen What is considered plagiarism on the site is not a matter of opinion.  Just because you personally don't think that copying the content of others, rather than only using others' work to supplement one's one, shouldn't be considered plagiarism, doesn't change the fact that *the site's guidelines on plagiarism state the opposite*.  Stating that this, in the content of posts *here*, it's not plagiarism, is just objectively false.  You were the one going around trying to correct other's statements about what plagiarism is, despite your own sources contradicting you.

Comment: @Servy *Sigh* The SE page I linked is about referencing. It briefly defines plagiarism as "posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own", which is not identical to failing to provide proper attribution. We agree not providing appropriate minimum attribution is grounds for removal of the content. You just call the entire thing "plagiarism", whereas I and the page I linked on referencing make a distinction between "plagiarism" and providing the minimum attribution required by the that page. [Note: the minimum required there is less than what's required by CC BY-SA 3.0.]

Comment: @CodyGray *Most* quoted material on Stack Overflow doesn't name the author. Yes, it's written in our policy, but frankly, our written policy is *ludicrously* overzealous. As I read it, it purportedly applies not only to quotes but to *all links*, implying that anyone who's ever included a link in an answer without somehow identifying and listing the authors of the linked content (a frequently impossible task) is officially a plagiarist. You have yourself [quoted from MSDN articles without identifying their authors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8861895/1709587); should I flag you for plagiarism?

Comment: @Mark There are many salient differences between the two examples. Obviously the author of MSDN articles is unknown, and we would never expect people to cite that. More importantly, we're talking about answers posted to Stack Overflow, which are licensed under our license agreement requiring attribution. Nobody has to guess about who the author was, because it's displayed prominently. I also think you're misreading the Help Center. It is intended to apply to quotations taken from other sources. When you have them, you need to have links and attribution. Not the other way around.

Comment: I get very irritated when people suggest that a question Q1 should be closed as a duplicate of Q2 simply because both have the same answer. It should only be closed as a duplicate if Q1 and Q2 are the same question. In my experience it's very common for two completely different questions to have the same answer, basically because two users have made the same or very similar mistakes but the consequences of the mistake are completely different depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Sorry, It was me! It's ok to link to other answers on SO. Yes, we need to give attribution, so a link to the author's profile is optimal. But, the answers were completely the same, and really don't offer value. So I should have deleted it.

To be completely honest, I'm not even sure what I was thinking.

[image]
^^ seriously, this *is* me sometimes.

Comment: No harm done. Just wanted to know if I was in the wrong, or of there was some mod-disagreement in regards on how to deal with this. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: BTW "LOL" is Estonian for dunce -- I learned this in chat playing chess online with someone from Estonia

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually inclined to defend Yvette's decision to decline this flag, even if [she herself now thinks it was the wrong call](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380511/1709587).

If a short quote from a source is sufficient to answer a question - whether that source is external or is another Stack Overflow post - then so be it. That's not, in itself, a problem with an answer. It is a clue (*not* a guarantee, but a clue) that the question being answered is bad or is a duplicate, but not grounds for bringing down the mods on the *answer*, in my view.

In this case, there *are* some reasons to be annoyed at the answer you flagged:

- It's not really an answer to the question. It's answering a question that isn't specific to Internet Explorer with information that *is* specific to Internet Explorer; that's unhelpful.
- It's crediting the other Stack Overflow post as the source of the quote, but really that other Stack Overflow post is itself quoting from the MSDN docs. It would've been more useful to the reader to quote the original source.

But these aren't points requiring moderator intervention. The first is a reason to downvote, and the second can be solved with an edit (or just a grumpy comment, if you think that the answer is unsalvageably bad for the first reason and don't want to contribute any work that'll help preserve it). But neither issue makes the answer a rules violation or an exceptional case requiring mod action. It's just another crap answer on a site with millions of them.

For those reasons, I'd've downvoted, commented, and moved on.

In any case, even if you *do* think that the issues above justify moderator action, you didn't highlight them in your flag comment. Instead, you just complained that the answer was nothing but a quote (with attribution), which in my view isn't even a problem in the first place. If it were, then the [original answer by Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1164921/1709587) would be equally deserving of moderator action; why didn't you also flag that one?

Comment: Maybe my flag explanation wasn't clear enough, I agree with you there. But seemed quite obvious what was the problem, and the decline reason made me think the mod had understood the flag. The problem is that this is a 100%  copy from another existing answer. There are multiple mod answers lying around that say that these are good candidates for deletion and that mod flags can be raised for those. See the answer by Boltclock I linked in my question, and the answer by Cody Grant he linked in a comment. I happen to agree with those answers.

Comment: There is nothing flaggable about Quentin's answer. It's a quote properly attributed, it's not a copy of an existing answer. The comparison is moot, IMO.

Comment: My flag did say "it's a repost of a different answer", with a link to the original. Although the link was pointing to the question, not the answer. My bad there as well.

Comment: I support this line of reasoning. I still need to provide people with constant expectations when flagging.  Though this was an edge case. Not plagiarism but just duplicating content.  Tbh if attribution is there but not done 100% correctly,  I'd prefer people edit than flag. But for duplicate content mod help is often needed.

Comment: @yivi Hmm. Interesting. On balance, BoltClock's answer persuades me. I suppose a total copy-and-paste of an answer will almost always indicate either a dupe question or (as in this case) an incomplete or irrelevant answer. Eh. I'll leave this answer up for people to contemplate and/or downvote, but I do now think it's misguided.

Comment: @yivi your flag was fine. I vagued out when handling it ECNUD

Answer (score -5):

The real question I would be asking is this: are the questions duplicates? If yes, there is your problem. If no, the answers are both posted in completely different contexts (and both seem to work in their relative contexts, as they both have positive scores.)  Therefore, they are not the same even if they are the same.

To illustrate my point, I will use an extreme example. Every 'yes-or-no' question that was ever asked, was answered in one of two ways. Even though the answer is always the same, the road to the answer is usually different.