# Can I use a comment to ask why an answer is being upvoted?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation, plagiarism

Regarding the following question:
[What should be the type of the state using react and typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70787299/what-should-be-the-type-of-the-state-using-react-and-typescript)
<sup>[Screenshot of answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OvDK.png)</sup>

---

The first answer, that also has been accepted has a score of `-1` and was posted **23 hours ago**.

**13 minutes ago**, a new user literally copy-pasted the accepted answer, which has a total score of `3` while writing this.

---

I placed a comment, something like

> Why is this answer getting so many upvotes if it's a literal copy of the [accepted answer from 23 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70787500/5625547)

To my surprise, my comment was deleted.

---

**Questions**

1. Why was my comment deleted?
2. How should I deal with copy/pasted, highly upvoted answers?

   - As suggested in [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320351/how-to-handle-copy-and-pasted-answers-from-dupes), I've raised a mod flag.

Comment: Not really, just like asking why a post is downvoted, asking why a post is upvoted is also rarely useful (and rightly deleted). Just flag the answer and let the community/mod deal with it.

Comment: Smells fishy. Answer was added 20 minutes ago and got three upvotes - first one was 23 seconds after posting, 25 seconds later the second, then 15 later came the third. And the account already upvoted 8 times since they got the privilege 20 minutes ago.

Comment: Definitely needs a custom mod flag for suspicious voting. Commenting to ask why is pointless; the voting ring (if there is one) would just flag the comment as NLN.

Comment: Yea @VLAZ thats why I'm asking this. Curious if this is a upvote-scam, or just his friends that are trying to boost his account.

Comment: @0stone0 what the difference? Both are voting fraud.

Comment: And just like that, the post is gone, and the account nuked.

Comment: The comment was comment flagged as "no longer needed" by three socks and fell under the auto-deletion criteria. I've dealt with the socks involved in that particular answer

Comment: Restored the balance has been.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. Kinda new to detecting/flagging suck posts. Learning how to deal with them. @VLAZ  I thought there was a slight difference, but thinking twice, they are the same.

Comment: @Zoe could you please clarify 'Socks'? As in puppets? Mods? Never head that before.

Comment: @0stone0 sockpuppets. Alternate accounts controlled by the same person (or sometimes same group of people). A lot of times used for fraud of some sort.

Comment: Sock (plural socks) is short for sockpuppet, i.e. an account that isn't someone's main account. If you create a second account, that account is a sock. There's cases where these are fine, to be clear (I'm sure someone else can link some meta posts on that), but using them to commit vote fraud generally results in their deletion

Comment: [What are the rules governing multiple accounts (i.e. sockpuppets)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388984/8839059),

Comment: [socks](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/shadows-socks) ...

Comment: @rene Good god. It's very painful when the tea goes down the wrong pipe.

Comment: The answer to "why are people upvoting" is much simpler to "why are people downvoting" - either it is because people think the answer is useful/correct, or because of some other reason that the upvoters won't want to admit to because it's against the rules. So it's a useless question to ask; in this case, if the votes are in good faith then it must be because the voters don't realise it's plagiarised, so a more useful comment would be just to say that it's plagiarised (and, of course, report it).

Comment: @rene: [Pair them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415881/)

Comment: It's better to comment to just explain what's wrong with the answer ("This answer is an exact copy of ..."). Asking why people are upvoting here seems almost rhetorical: If they aren't aware of the problem, then they might just be upvoting a post that seems useful. If they are aware of the problem, then they're either malicious or indifferent to quality standards. If you find something to be suspicious (and possibly against the rules), then it's better to raise a custom flag so a mod can investigate and deal with it.

Comment: It's not always sock puppets. I've recently noticed (or suspected) a similar behavior ...which involved copied content, combined with excessive formatting and the sales argument, that it would be "new", also an irregular high vote count. This are click-baiting strategies; (appearently) fabricated questions are also trending, since asking questions bring reputation.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

- Why was my comment deleted?
  Because comments are meant to ask for clarification of the post. They are not a means to have a jolly debate about voting behavior of other users.
- How should I deal with copy/pasted, highly upvoted answers?
  Downvote. If it is a blatant copy flag for a mod as plagiarism. If you suspect that (sock) puppets are involved in voting on the dubious content, flag for a mod and explain why you feel the voting is out of bounds.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to use a flag (for moderator attention) in the future if you suspect rule breaking because you need to alert mods directly. The answer was flagrant plagiarism. Even putting that aside, the upvotes were very suspicious and would warrant a flag in themselves. Mods are not alerted to comments and, as you saw, comments can sometimes be deleted (which in this case seems to have been related to the apparent voting ring, but under some circumstances happens with one flag). The only reason I would leave a comment under circumstances like yours is to warn other users of what's happening.  (Plagiarism isn't always obvious since you sometimes don't read all the answers.)

If, on the other hand, you notice a technical problem in an answer, a comment would be appropriate, and it would be effective to word it like: "Am I missing something? This is a lot slower than [link to the other answer]."

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, the late answer is a blatant copy/paste of the existing one. This is clearly plagiarism which is not ok. It is ok to point out such in comments, but you need to be explicit "why was this *plagiarised* answer up-voted". Asking why people vote in a way in general through comments isn't productive.

Apart from the unacceptable plagiarism, there might also be strange things going on in the background here, like sock puppet accounts voting. So we need a moderator to investigate it.

What you should do here:

- Copy the URL to the first answer.
- Flag the late answer with a custom reason. Write "This is plagiarism of an already existing answer here:" Insert URL.
- Optionally  leave a comment about the answer being plagiarized and down-vote it.

In this specific case, the plagiarized answer has by now been deleted by a moderator and the user account who posted it no longer exists either.

Answer (score -4):

It has been asked many, many times throughout all those years.

> How should I deal with copy/pasted, highly upvoted answers?

Move on.

That's the only real answer you'll get.

"Raise a flag" is just a self-deception. It only works if supplied with a post on Meta. Otherwise it will be silently dismissed. *Nobody* cares if someone getting "unfair" reputation points. Rather the opposite.

Most people do not understand at first, what Stack Overflow is about. It is not about such silly stuff like "knowledge", "good answers" or "fair play". If you look at the system closely, *what is really rewarded here*, it is all about reputation and badges. As long as the answer gives you reputation points, it's a good answer. Gives you a badge? Even better. That's all. Want more badges? Do some garbage stuff like mass editing some silly typo. That's what is rewarded here.

Any attempt to clarify some blatant hoax will be considered as a disrupting behavior. You are spoiling people's fun. And having fun is all that Stack Overflow really about. Take it or leave it.

Comment: Very cynical and not completely true, but not completely false either. You have some valid points. :)

Comment: I am very surprised by this answer. I've had no problem at all dealing with plagiarism and similar via flagging; the mod team usually handles these very appropriately and thoroughly, as far as I can tell.

Comment: No. In contrast to the company's very unfortunate attitude to plagiarism (approaching that of Quora's and [DEV's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541940/map-vs-object-in-javascript#comment124183547_49164774)), most Stack Overflow moderators actually take plagiarism seriously. At least the particular posts that are flagged. I don't know about the users in question - in any case, you should provide ALL the information so the moderators don't have to do it.

Comment: I've flagged plagiarism many times and the moderators have always taken it seriously, from what I can tell often with disciplinary consequences for the poster. I can't recall a single scenario where they ignored my flag and the plagiarized answer was allowed to remain.